# Standard TableView Cell - label text overlaps with uiimage

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is happening but I don't know why. It is a standard tableviewcell with a label and an image on it

[image: text overlapping with image]

Here is the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = patientsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "patientTableViewCell", for: indexPath)
    let text = "Bob Marley"
    cell.textLabel?.text = text
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Provide relevant code

Comment: unwanted frames values please provide the code or storyboard screenshots.

Comment: Can you show your storyboard screenshot? And your attribute inspector too. There seems some issue with the style

Answer (score 0):

When I do not put an image view in the object inspector but like below, it solves the problem. I am not sure why though

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "patients")
```